# Docker build uisng a proxy from host system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, proxy

I want to use a proxy for docker build. I checked with solution like this:

```
sudo docker build -t Cron/ubuntu \
            --build-arg http_proxy="http://myproxy.example.com:8080" \
            --build-arg https_proxy="https://myproxy.example.com:8080" \
```

But in my situation, the proxy ip is not a internet address but some ip from the host system like this: `0.0.0.0:8118`.

I think when I use `--buid-arg` to build the image, and the dockerfile run to some thing like `apt-get`, the container will try to use `0.0.0.0:8118` from the docker system instead of the host system. And since I haven't configured that ip for the docker system like the host system, the proxy would be invalid.

So my question is, how can I run `docker build` uisng a proxy from host system? Is there some way to map the ip from host to docker container?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not a valid actual address, it just tells the server to accept connections on any network interface, with any address. You have to know the server's real internal IP address on the Docker internal pseudo-network and pass that in.

Comment: See https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1143

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file in ~/.docker/config.json file like this:

```
{
  "proxies":{
    "httpProxy":"http://proxy_url:proxy_port",
    "httpsProxy":"https://proxy_url:proxy_port",
    "ftpProxy":"ftp://proxy_url:proxy_port"
  }
}
```

Then call docker like so:

```
sudo docker build -t Cron/ubuntu --build-arg http_proxy --build-arg https_proxy --build-arg ftp_proxy
```

This functionality was implemented in this PR:
https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/32966

Any ideas to make this UX better please contribute here:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30323